# countdown.js other formatting

Tags: javascript, regex, countdown

I'm using the very good script from http://countdownjs.org/ and pretty much all is working well. However, I want the format without the *strings* **hours, minutes, seconds** - just a plain timer (hh:mm:ss).
I was thinking about a regex but this is very ineffective, I guess.
So is there a better way?
This is the code I have so far (which works, but in a very ineffective way):

```
var now = new Date();
var totalEnd = now.setHours(now.getHours() + 8);
var timeString = countdown( null, totalEnd, countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS ).toString();
if (timeString) {
    timeString = timeString.replace(/\s?hours?,|\s?minutes?,/gi, ':');
    timeString = timeString.replace(/\s|and|seconds?/gi, '');
    // now I have a timestring with hh:mm:ss
    // but I want to avoid the regex
}
```

Comment: [Read the manual](http://countdownjs.org/readme.html)

Comment: I did. Unfortunately nothing about how to get rid of the strings in question.

Comment: Could you post what you have now? My guess would be to use *the units argument* from the manual

Comment: One sentence is in opposite to another: „I want the format without hours, minutes, seconds - just a plain timer (hh:mm:ss)”, what you want to show?

Comment: Thanks for both comments. To clarify, I want to have the format without the *strings* "hours, minutes, seconds".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why putting it to a string instead of using the given object ?
You would then be able to get the variables you need without doing some string replacements.
For instance :

```
var now = new Date();
var totalEnd = now.setHours(now.getHours() + 8);
var time = countdown( null, totalEnd, countdown.HOURS|countdown.MINUTES|countdown.SECONDS );
alert(time.days);
```